# Algorithm: Find if a there's a path from a vertex to every other vertices in a directed graph?

Tags: graph

Given a directed graph. I want an algorithm that finds, if there is a path between a vertex v to all other vertices in the graph? In time complexity (|V| + |E|).

I'm not sure how to proceed with this problem. A little help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Make a recursive algorithm, step by step: 1.- Take the start vertex v, mark it as Checked. 2.- Retrieve all the connected vertex to it and call the Same fucntion to it, if the vertex is already checked, stop the recursive call. 3.- Check if all nodes are checked.

Comment: Added as answer, i can make an example on code if you add a lenguage tag to the question with the desired language (in case i know it, prefered: c++, python, haskell, java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive version for check connected vertex Pseudocode:

```
Object Vertex {position, list_of_connected_vertex, already_checked}
Object Graph  {list_of_all_vertex}

function checkConnected(initial_vertex):
    if initial_vertex is already_checked:
        return
    else:
        initial_vertex.already_checked = true
        for vertex in initial_vertex.list_of_connected_vertex:
            checkConnected(vertex)

if all_are_checked(Graph.list_of_all_vertex) then Vertex is connected.
```

(Clear the flags already_checked for other vertex and graph check)

Is a natural way of think about the problem, not the best performance way for it probably.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is just finding out if a path between a single pair of vertices exists, [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) can be used. If the existence of a path for a specific fixed graph, but various combinations of vertices is to be repeated, a [connected component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) might be more suitable.

Comment: The problem is if a given vertex in a graph is connected to every other vertex on it.